# Iframe disappears on Safari Reload only

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, safari

I am encountering a strange issue that I'm hoping is a simple fix. I am just dipping my toes in the world on HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am trying to dynamically resize my iframe content via JavaScript and CSS triggered when a page loads. The code below works great in Chrome and Edge but only partially in Safari.

Upon first page load in safari the iframe sizes and loads properly without issue. However if I hit the refresh button on the browser the Iframe disappears. Where it gets really strange is if, for example, on IPhone, I put my screen to sleep. Then awaken the phone and reload the page in safari the iframe then displays again.

I know that the code below isn't the cleanest. Its really just my naïve attempt at making an Iframe perfectly fit the size of a browser window. The iframe source is a published google sheet with a known content width of 1900px and height of 1250px.  Help Please!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />




<style>
    #wrap {
        width: 912px;
        height: 600px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #frame {
        width: 1900px;
        height: 1250px;
        border: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(0.48);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.48);
        -o-transform: scale(0.48);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.48);
        transform: scale(0.48);
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body onload="ss()">

<div id="wrap">

    <iframe id="frame" src="insert_iframe_here"></iframe>

</div>



<script>
function ss() {
      var sw = window.innerWidth;
      var sh = window.innerHeight;
      var swp = sw / 1900;
      var swpr = Math.round(swp * 100) / 100;
      var shp = swpr * sh;
      var shpr = Math.round(shp);

      document.getElementById("wrap").style.width = sw;
      document.getElementById("wrap").style.height = shpr;
      document.getElementById("frame").style.webkitTransform = "scale(" + swpr + ")";
      document.getElementById("frame").style['-ms-transform'] = "scale(" + swpr + ")";
      document.getElementById("frame").style.transform = "scale(" + swpr + ")";
      document.getElementById("frame").style['-moz-transform'] = "scale(" + swpr + ")";
      document.getElementById("frame").style['-o-transform'] = "scale(" + swpr + ")";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't see an error on the first view. May you try to put a `console.log("foo");` in your `ss()`-Function and check, if the function gets executed if you reload in safari?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The console is logging that JavaScript is executing on reload